# How to avoid WebDriverException caused by Firefox updates

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Several times I have faced this issue: I run my `Python-Selenium` script using `Firefox`, but instead of browser window, updates downloading pop-up appears and I get WebDriverException: `"The browser appears to have exited "`. Just after download completed browser window opens, but script is already stopped.. So how can I avoid script exit and force webdriver to wait until `Firefox` updates completion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable auto update by passing custom `FirefoxProfile` when you open the 
browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('app.update.auto', False)
fp.set_preference('app.update.enabled', False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to disable autoupdate manually Options>Advanced>Update by "Never check for updates" radio btn. In my case its better idea because I have full control of compability between FF and WebDriver version then. Once I want to move to newer/newest version I do it via Help>About Firefox or if Im interested in specific version I can always download it [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)